# Allocate/Deallocate dynamic array of struct pointers in C

Tags: ios, c, pointers, struct

say i have the following two struct definitions in C.

```
struct child { 
int x;
};

struct Yoyo { 
struct child **Kids;
};
```

How would i go about allocating the memory for Kids.

say for example i have some function Yoyo_create().

```
static struct Yoyo * yoyo_create() {

 int n = 32000;

struct Yoyo *y;

y = malloc(sizeof( *Yoyo));

y->Kids = malloc(n*sizeof(*Child));

for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) { y->Kids[i] = NULL; }

}
```

and then to destroy the Kids in some "destructor function" i would do.

```
void yoyo_destroy(struct yoyo *y)
{
free(y->Kids);
free(y);
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: `sizeof` needs a type name or an expression of the desired type.  Your `malloc(sizeof( *Yoyo))` should probably be `malloc(sizeof(struct Yoyo))` or `malloc(sizeof(*y))`, and `sizeof(*Child)` should probably be `sizeof(struct Child)`...

Comment: @Dmitri `sizeof(struct Child*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need these lines

```
y->Kids = malloc(n*sizeof(*Child)); and <br>
free(y->Kids);
```

because your y contains kids structure in it. And except these , you are going well

Answer (score 0):

y = malloc(sizeof(struct Yoyo));

y->Kids = malloc(n*sizeof(struct Child));

Comment: I think `struct child *`

Comment: Wouldn't that allocate memory for a pointer then, which would be 4 bytes?